# Important and recommended skills for a pilot just starting out?

Tags: eve-online

I have just started playing EVE Online and I was wondering is there are any skills that I should learn as soon as possible that will open up more of the game and/or increase my survivability in New Eden.

In particular I'm looking for skills I should pick up, but anything else that I'm missing is also welcomed!

In general I'd want to just fly around, make some money and learn the basics of the game, I don't have much of an understanding of the game but so far I have been doing the exploration career missions and will probably be looking towards doing the Industry or Business missions once I have finished the ones I'm doing.

Comment: Whatever recommendations you get, I advise plugging them into evemon or some other skill planner, to get an idea for the optimal attribute spread in your first few months (and to have the skill order and skill list set in stone, as opposed to chaotically adding them whenever).

Comment: You have to give us a rough idea of what your character is meant to do. Do you want to fly around and shoot stuff? Do you want to trade? Do you want to produce stuff?

Comment: @Fadeway I really wouldn't try to optimize attributes for the first few months. You have to learn many basic skills with different attributes in the beginning, and a new player will have a very hard time planning far enough in advance for an effective remap. You get a 20-25% advantage with an optimal remap, that isn't enough to outweigh the severe loss in flexibility early on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do, as certain PVE/PVP skills aren't terribly useful to an industry pilot, and many industry skills are useless to a PVE/PVP pilot.

That being said, career choices can be broken down as follows:

- Industry - Mining, Blueprint Research, Invention, Manufacturing (T1/T2/T3), and more
- Combat - PVE (Missions/Incursions/Sites) PVP (Ganks, Pirating, Factional Warfare), and more
- Trading - Trade in station and make spacebucks or haul goods around

There are various niches in each of these career "paths", but each has an overarching idea to the types of skills you would want to train if you were to head down them.

**Combat** is easily the most daunting, because there's so much to do and so much to train. In my opinion, the best thing to do is focus on one race at least until you have a handle on how that race works, then it's relatively easy to branch out and train other race's ships/guns.

That means if you're **Amarr**, train for **Amarr Frigate**, **Amarr Cruiser**, **Amarr Battleship** etc. (It should be noted that as of January 7, 2013, The Destroyers and Battlecruiser skills are not split up by race, but the makers of Eve have stated that they will be split in the near future). Find out which weapon type your race uses, and train the corresponding skills. Amarr use lasers, Minmatar use Artillery and Autocannons, Caldari use missiles and hybrids(rails/blasters), Gallente use hybrids and drones.

More importantly however, is if you intend on being a combat pilot, train your **capacitor** skills and your **tanking** skills. Every race needs to use capacitor for something, and training those skills will never be a waste. The most important Cap skills are **Energy Systems Operation and Energy Management**. Tanking depends mostly on the race of ships you're flying. Amarr and Gallente (mostly) armor tank, whereas Caldari and Minmatar (mostly) shield tank.

The armor tanking skills **Mechanic, Hull Upgrades, and Repair Systems** will serve you well.

Shield tanking is slightly more skill intensive, with the main skills being **Shield Operation, Shield Management, Shield Compensation, Shield Upgrades**

Another set of insanely useful skills to train includes **Engineering, Electronics, Weapon Upgrades/Advanced Weapon Upgrades**. These skills will allow your ship to have more powergrid, more cpu, and make your weapons use less of cpu and powergrid. It is impossible for ships to be fit optimally without training these skills, so you will never regret them.

An important avenue that is useful for almost every single pilot (especially gallente), is drones. There are drones that do almost everything in the game, and if you intend to be a combat pilot, you *will* want them. Skills to use drones include **Drones**, **Drone Interfacing**, **Scout Drone Operation**, **Mining Drone Operation**, and many, many more.

As for industry, there are less globally important skills to have, as each has it's niche. If you intend to mine, train **mining, astrogeology, mining barge** to get started. If you intend on refining the minerals you mine, then learn **Refining** and **Refinery Efficiency**. Most mining skills are found in the industry tab or science tab.

If you intend to manufacture goods, **Production Efficiency** is vitally important.

Invention is a more complex career that involves various skills ranging from science and industry to electronics/engineering.

Trading is the easiest career path to explain since you pretty much train all the skills in the trade tab, and do market research and buy stuff to sell later. The recommended skills are **Broker Relations, Marketing, Trade, Daytrading** and **Procurement**.

I feel it necessary to put a disclaimer here and say that I'm no expert in any of the careers I mentioned above, nor am I an expert in Eve. Nor is my answer a comprehensive guide of all the skills required to do any of the above mentioned activities at peak efficiency. This was only an introductory look at some of the skills that will always be useful for certain avenues in this game. I also glossed over less complex (skillwise) careers like trading and invention.

Comment: Great post, I will add that you can read http://www.isktheguide.com/ for lots of good information. Also the EVE-O forums skills discussion forum has a pretty good community for helping you tailor your skill plan to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you'd like to do this is a really though question.

As a first start, pick a frigate you'd like to fly and the equipment you'd like to use (like guns or support modules, such as defensive/tank items). This should give you a rough idea on what you'll want to learn first.

After this, heading for the first few levels of certificates (accessible through the character window) won't hurt either. They are grouped by different categories and professions, so you should be able to find something that's going to fit your playstyle. Just don't try to not play the game till you've got all at standard or improved or anything like that, because most of the higher ones I'd consider "overkill", especially for a new player.

For the start you should be able to use the following items:

- Frigate of your choice (combat, mining or hauling)
- Turrets of your choice (these could be weapons or things such as mining lasers)
- Tank modules of your choice (either shield or armor tank; this really depends on your personal preference and your ship choice (race))
- Further support modules to fill empty slots in your ship while making it more effective (for a trader these could be Cargohold Expanders for example).

Answer (score 0):

I will begin my answer with [this diagram](http://endie.net/img/eve/eve-wtd.jpg).

---

EVE is an insanely expansive game. The Skill Certificates are actually a decent guideline for new players looking to get things done. Depending on what exactly you plan to do, I would find a group that actively does that in game and poke them for some advice on what sort of skills you should pick up.

For some good all around skills, though, @Khrave has a good selection of skills. Depending on which specific race you intend to play, there will be a couple of different focuses ( spaceship skills, gunnery/missile skills, cap/shield/armor skills, etc. ). A nice balance is to train a little bit of everything until you understand how/what each skill does to help you.

Because there are so many skills in the game, however, giving you a comprehensive list of skills to train is prohibitive. I'm sure if you update your question with what exact path you'd like to embark on, the community will be able to give you more focused advice.